# Remove every 3rd and 4th element from array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have below array, i want to skip first 3 element from array (key - 0, 1, 2) and remove next 2 element(key - 3, 4). i.e - I want array like that, it skips every 1st 3 element and remove next 2 element after first 3. I tried below code, but it's not proper solution for that.

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($newArray); $i += 1) {
    if($i == 3 || $i == 4 || $i == 8 || $i == 9){
        unset($newArray[$i]);
    }
}
```

**Input array**

```
Array
    (
        [0] => 0.393
        [1] => 0.769
        [2] => 0.189
        [3] => 0
        [4] => 0
        [5] => 0.349
        [6] => 0.686
        [7] => 0.168
        [8] => 0
        [9] => 0
        [10] => 0.272
        [11] => 0.534
        [12] => 0.131
        [13] => 1
        [14] => 0
    )

**Expected Output**

    Array
            (
                [0] => 0.393
                [1] => 0.769
                [2] => 0.189
                [3] => 0.349
                [4] => 0.686
                [5] => 0.168
                [6] => 0.272
                [7] => 0.534
                [8] => 0.131
            )
```

Comment: are you aiming to remove only the `integers` and keep the `float` values?

Comment: No i want to remove skip 1st 3 element from and then unset next 2, again skip 3 and unset next 2 like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`array_filter`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php), using the `ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY` flag to pass the element keys to the filter function, and remove all entries whose `key % 5` is not `< 3`:

```
$newArray = array_filter($newArray, function ($k) { return $k % 5 < 3; }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY );
print_r($newArray);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0.393
    [1] => 0.769
    [2] => 0.189
    [5] => 0.349
    [6] => 0.686
    [7] => 0.168
    [10] => 0.272
    [11] => 0.534
    [12] => 0.131
)
```

Note that if you want the array values 0-indexed, you can pass the result through `array_values`:

```
$newArray = array_values($newArray);
print_r($newArray);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0.393
    [1] => 0.769
    [2] => 0.189
    [3] => 0.349
    [4] => 0.686
    [5] => 0.168
    [6] => 0.272
    [7] => 0.534
    [8] => 0.131
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/fJake)

Comment: It's working for me. Can we do it without array filter? Also can you explain the solution which you gave so it's helpful.

Comment: @user8989878 array_filter returns the elements of the array for which the function returns true. By passing the array key to the function and taking it modulo 5, the first 3 keys are 0-2, the next two 3-4, the next three 0-2 again, the next two 3-4 etc. etc. So if we return true when the key value is 0, 1 or 2 we will return the values as you desire.

Comment: You could build a solution using a simple foreach loop, for example https://3v4l.org/i3IIr